# calloc works when debugging, hangs when running

Tags: c++

I have a c++ program which I'm running on a windows 7 64bit machine, using Eclipse as my IDE. I use mingw32 for a compiler.

**The problem**: When I debug the program using the gdb debugger it runs just fine and does what it needs to do. But when I run it without debugging, either from the command line or from within eclipse (using the same configuration as with the debug), it crashes. 
I tried running the program from the command line and attaching to the process using the debugger, and what I saw is that it reaches the following line of code:

```
anc_map[ancestry].hap_array = (char**)calloc(anc_map[ancestry].nr_hap , sizeof(char*));
```

and just hangs (cpu is not working, and nothing happens although the program is still running).

The above line is actually called more than once, and the hanging occurs the second time it is called (it works the first time).

Any idea what can be the cause for this behavior?

Thanks,
Itamar.

**Edit**:

1. I realize that using *calloc* is a little old-fashioned, but since this is a legacy code I just need to modify a little, I'm trying to avoid doing major refactoring.
2. I've tried compiling the code and running on linux, and the problem does not occur there, so it has something to do with my configuration on the windows machine

Comment: Don't use `malloc`/`calloc` in C++.

Comment: I would first check the values of `anc_map`, `ancestry` and `anc_map[ancestry].nr_hap`, and start using `new`, which is the standard C++ allocation method.

Comment: Further to @OliCharlesworth's comment, your code suggests very strongly that you are going about C++ in a very questionable way, and if that's true, then you will be in a never-ending world of pain and bugs. It might be worth (re)familiarising yourself with proper, modern C++ techniques and idioms.

Comment: There is nothing like "modern, proper C++ techniques and idioms". C++ is an old, unsafe language, it should be treated as so, and using calloc in C++ is just fine. This is what's the worst about C++ community - one comes to ask about a problem, and gets absolutely irrelevant answer, mostly something of likes "use a smart pointer" "don't use malloc" "make it a template" or similar bullshit.

Comment: @user1279560, please try to break your problem down to as small piece of code as possible, and if you don't come to your solution when doing that, then post the whole replicable test case here and maybe it'll be possible to help you out. Knowing what types, sizes etc things are would be valuable to find your answer.

Comment: @q66 I could not agree more. Most of the time someone feels bad just for asking, and it is those users that know the most, that look down the most those that pose the questions. Those of us that are here to help though think differently.

Comment: check the values of `ancestry` and `nr_hap`.

Comment: My gut tells me you're corrupting memory somehow.  Use one of the diagnostic allocator libs.  One is built into MSVS.  There is also Horde and tcmalloc (though I am not sure tcmalloc works with Windows MinGW)

Comment: @q66: No, that's nonsense.  There's no reason to use `calloc` unless you're having to interact with a legacy C API, or reimplementing the internals of `new`.  For everyday coding, there's *always* a far superior approach.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, new is not any superior, it's pretty much equal solution and it's not much safer, either. And it's clear the asker's problem would NOT be solved by swapping calloc for new. So your answer is completely irrelevant to his question.

Comment: @q66: `new` is cleaner and safer than `calloc`, but a container class would be much better than either.  A newcomer to C++ should not be fiddling around with raw pointers like this.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, arguably. Doesn't change the fact your answer was irrelevant to his question.

Comment: @q66: That's why I placed it as a comment, rather than as an answer.

Comment: As a guess.. are you trying to dereference any of the pointers (from the array of pointers) without initializing?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is whether `anc_map[ancestry].nr_hap` could be some bogus, probably huge, number. Probably because any of the variables got corrupt. I am not sure why it would get corrupt only without debugger, but it might be that the debugger affects where things are allocated and the corruption appears somewhere less harmful when debugging.

The other thing that comes to mind is, that if the program needs a lot of memory, the debugger might affect the 2-GB limit flag in Windows, so in one case there is enough memory and the other way you run out. I am, however, not sure how to change it with mingw32 compiler, as I only did it with the Microsoft one (/LARGEADDRESSAWARE option to Microsoft `link` and `editbin`). The reason is, that in some old software, they noticed people doing binary search like `(whatever *)(((unsigned)begin + (unsigned)end)/2)`, which, besides being incorrect C, does not work if the pointers are above 2GB, because the calculation overflows. So for old software, written before more than 2GB was common, they limited the memory to 2GB and provided option to get more, which means 3GB on 32-bit Windows (the last 1GB maps kernel space to avoid swapping page tables on kernel entry and exit; linux does the same thing) and 4GB for 32-bit process on 64-bit windows (the kernel can be mapped above 4GB there).

Hm, but most likely it's actually corruption of the memory management metadata, because that's the usual case where memory allocation or deallocation functions just hang instead of returning an error. Again the debugger would cause some addresses to be different and the corruption to happen elsewhere.

In the first and last case the corruption would probably be always there, so you might have some luck trying to run it:

- In linux under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).
- Under [DUMA](http://duma.sourceforge.net), but the Microsoft standard runtime library will try to resist replacing the memory allocation functions rather hard; I finally gave up when I found that IO streams use something like __debug_delete, but normal new. Or the other way around; I don't recall exactly.In either case one was the standard allocation function and the other was some their internal undocumented function. It will also use much more memory than usual, because each allocation will be at least 8kB. In Linux it's trivial, because GNU libc has special support for overriding memory allocation, but valgrind is superior there anyway.